# LWUIT implementation of XML Parsing and Storage

Tags: xml, parsing, java-me, lwuit

Storage, Network Connections, and Parsing have been optimized/added to the new LWUIT 1.5, but some of us novices still don't know how to use the classes.

I am trying to do the following:
1.  connect to the network - send username and password to an online page
2.  parse the returned XML results and store them.

Can someone please help me by giving me a short example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several examples of how to do the former, see the Browser demo, Chat demo (from Chen's incubator directory) & makeover demo.

Login depends on the method you are using to login, e.g. basic authentication just requires a user header with the appropriate values. You can add a header using `NetworkManager.addDefaultHeader()`.

There is indeed a lack of XML parsing tutorials but generally this should be relatively easy.

```
XMLParser p = new XMLParser();
Element e = p.parse();
Vector children = e.getChildren(); 
Hashtable attributes = e.getAttributes();
```

To store XML I would just store the XML String itself since LWUIT doesn't provide the facility to save parsed XML data.

```
Storage.getInstance().writeObject("NameOfObject", xmlString);
String xmlString = Storage.getInstance().readObject("NameOfObject");
```

Comment: Thanks Shai! I have been able to implement the network connection successfully - I was even able to add a Button to Cancel the connection to the waitscreen Dialog, but there is a small cause for worry. I keep getting the InterruptedException. Will that affect the application adversely?

Comment: That's a separate question but I'm guessing its the timeout of the LWUIT4IO code. Since there is no way to timeout a connection in J2ME we use tricks such as thread interrupt invocations.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it asap